# Can't type in input type text within <a> tag in Edge Browser?

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

Scripting Language : AngularJS

My Html Code is :

```
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<label ng-if="show">MyName</label>
<i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-if="show">
<i class="fa fa-trash" ng-if="show">
<input type="text" ng-hide="show" />
</a>
</li>
```

this above html working in all browser excepting in IE edge..

this functionality done for , when i click on edit icon in list , label will remove and textbox will show with label value ..

its like editing list for whatever i will selected or renamed of that label value .

This html code working fine in (firefox,google chrome excepting IE9 above & Edge).

Comment: Why are you placing an input inside of an anchor? Also, there isn't any [tag:angularjs] here; this is just HTML. Can you also share any relevant Angular code you are using. Lastly, which version of Edge are you testing with? I just tested https://jsfiddle.net/39zhw2uf/ on a recent build, and was able to type into both input elements.

Comment: Anchor tags can only wrap non interactive content, so no inputs. That's invalid html. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with a html [validator](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Output is:

> Error: The element **input** must not appear as a descendant of the **a**
>   element.

So basically this isn't a valid HTML, it depends on the browsers on how strict they parse your markup. So you might want to use some workarounds in your code to get the same effect you want but not using that kind of markup.